# Using CSS Flex to span multiple columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use CSS Flex to have a second row span the 2nd and 3rd columns only.

I don't want to add it as a separate row below the first row created in column 1.

This is because the content of column 1 is a tall graphic and so the content of columns 2 and 3 do not need to create additional vertical space.

The content of row 2 in column 3 may also vary in height and it would be good to position the content that spans columns two and three below this.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2.5px solid blue;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2.5px solid black;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.double_column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 2;
  border: 2.5px solid red;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!---- Header ---->
<header style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px !important;">
</header>
<!---- Header end ---->
<div class="clear"></div>
<!--content area-->
<div class="project_area">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="row">
      row one

      <div class="column" style="width:45%; ">
        column one
      </div>

      <div class="column" style="width:20%;">
        column two

        <div class="row">
          <div class="double_column" style="padding-left:0px;">
            row 2 in column 2 <br /> want this to extend into column three below row 2 of column 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column" style="width:20%;">
        column three
        <div class="row">
          row two in column 3
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're looking to achieve? It's hard to follow here. Also, flex may not be the way to go, since there is no real delineation of `columns` and `rows`. You may want to look at CSS Grid instead.

Comment: have you looked at 'grid' - may be better fitting to the desired effect

Comment: I have looked at grid but that would seem to enforce a strict height on each row and I want the row heights to vary according to the content

Comment: Grid doesn't enforce strict height. Grid is simply a layout display. You can put in whatever content you want and the Grid will adjust its height.

Comment: please see this image of what I am wanting to achieve
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UHuT.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `flex`, you do need one more wrapper. You need to separate the left and right side content. Because `flex` has no concept of columns and rows (unlike CSS Grid), you essentially have to create two columns with the markup.

The `right` element is a flex parent and uses `align-content` and the children use `align-self: flex-start` so the children elements do not take up the full height of the parent.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.column {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: pink;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.column--extended {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!--content area-->
<div class="project_area">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x800">
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <div class="column">
        column two
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400">
      </div>

      <div class="column column--extended">
        Extended Row. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### GRID EXAMPLE

I commented all of the lines of CSS to explain what they are doing. For a really good tutorial, I always point people starting out with CSS Grid to: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  /* Sets up the grid to be three columns */
  grid-template-columns: 50% repeat(2, 1fr);
  /* We have two rows - the first is the height of the largest content in the row. The second is the the remainder of the height of the grid parent */
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
  /* 5px gap between grid elements */
  grid-gap: 5px;
  background: violet;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.column--image {
  /* We want the first column to span across all rows, so we go from line 1 to line 3 (top and bottom */
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.column--mid {
  /* we only want the height of this element to be its own height */
  height: max-content;
  background: pink;
}

.column--extended {
  /* Sets this up from row line 2 to 3 */
  grid-row: 2/3;
  /* we want to extend this from the left line of the second column to the last line of the columns */
  grid-column: 2/4;
  background: yellow;
  /* we only want the height of this element to be its own height */
  height: max-content;
}
```

```html
<!--content area-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column column--image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x500">
  </div>

  <div class="column column--mid">
    Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit.
  </div>


  <div class="column column--small-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400">
  </div>


  <div class="column column--extended">
    Extended Row. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect - thank you @disinfor for the code and the explanation
I will also try with grid to understand both approaches
thank you

Comment: I'm learning about Grid and Flexbox at the moment and Grid is best for layout and flexbox for components. You might find it's better do use Grid for this instead of flexbox for this reason.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Grid and Flex would both work for this - I say this as someone who knows both. Paul427, I'll add a Grid example later.

Comment: Hi @disinfor I should have clarified by saying "best suited" not "best". Of course you could use either one, but each is optimised for a purpose.

Comment: I don't think Grid is "best suited" for this particular layout. I think if the layout needed to follow a more robust "Grid" layout, I would probably agree. "Optimized" gets into opinion - since both examples achieve the same result with roughly the same amount of element properties : )